# How does photon reflection work quantum mechanically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, solid-state-physics, reflection

When a single photon strikes a mirror, it is reflected back such that the incident angle= the reflected angle. When the photon interacts with the surface lattice of the mirror, what exactly is happening? If the photon is absorbed, how does the surface lattice possibly "know" to emit it back at precisely the reflection angle? If the photon is not absorbed, how do their wavefunctions interact such that the trajectory of the photon is changed the same way every time?

Comment: If you accept that the reflection law for angles works for waves (including EM waves), then you should have no problem accepting that it works for photons too.